# iOS app validation warning. Will my app get rejected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to iTunes Connect. Prior to the recent iOS 7 and Xcode 5 update I had no issues, but now when I try to validate the app binary it gives me the following error:

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/AppName.app/AppName: startIndex
```

I have looked all over my code for `startIndex` but I'm not able to find it. Has anyone faced a similar problem? Will Apple reject my app because of this?

Comment: this may be because some third party library you are using is actually using some un-documented private API. In our case it was an old Google Analytics/Tracking SDK. Yes Apple can reject your app.

Comment: If you are using a Google API, there might be a fix here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=46

Comment: Hmm. Yes it does seem to be an issue with the Google API. Thank you for the link. :)

Comment: @BenPious. I tried the fix in the link. Didn't work. :/

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. If you have to submit to the App Store soon, I think somewhere along the line in the submission process there is a "notes to the reviewer" section you could explain the situation in... if they don't automatically reject you, maybe that'll get you through.

Comment: Hmm. I guess that could work. Thanks for the advice. :)